# Drupal 7: missing php code in default value

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm using Drupal 7.26 and i created a new content type.

I want to add a field that has a Default value where I can add PHP code. Normally, the Default value shows only plain text.

I have been activating *"php filter module"* and *"cck module"* for drupal 7.
But I cannot find the PHP code!!

How do I find this Item? Thank you.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5606/drupal-7-default-value-php-snippet-missing

Comment: https://drupal.org/node/794724

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at it differently.
PHP filter module will provide a text filter in which you would be able to enter php code.
However, the field type in which you add the php code needs to be "Large text" or "Large text with summary". In the field settings you have to enable the PHP filter, then you should be able to enter PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer But I don't want PHP code in this way! I want to have PHP code in default value part for all Types of field.

Comment: @Mrs.My Not sure why do you want to do that. Are you talking about syntax highlighting of the PHP code?

Comment: @Mrs.My Do you want to have PHP codes in default value part of the content?

Comment: @ajit-s Not at all! I only want to have "PHP code" in "default value part" in manage field of content.

Comment: @Mrs.My It is not recommended to enable the an editor / admin to enter PHP code directly. It might cause security loopholes. Any interaction with the code, database, should happen via modules, contributed or custom. This is because they follow the best practises and API specifications which covers (almost) all the security checks.